# Issue in Adding Custom Notification Ringer Sound in Flutter App for Background Notification Triggered by Backend

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add custom sound for the notifications that are being triggered, however, so far I haven't achieved any success.

Here is what I am doing, I added alarm.mp3 file in the raw folder.
[image]

This is how the backend team is sending the notification:

```
{
 "to" : "my_device_token",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "priority" : "high",
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Test Notification body for custom sound {{datestamp}}",
     "title": "Custom sound alert.mp3",
     "sound": "alert.mp3"
 }
}
```

Can you please guide me how can I achieve the custom sound of the notification, both in the background and in the foreground. Thank you.

Here is what I am doing, I added alarm.mp3 file in the raw folder.
[image]

Comment: I guess the backend team is trying to access the file “alert.mp3” but you have named your file “alarm.mp3”. Try changing the name.

Comment: Nope, I do have the file alert.mp3 on my end, the image that I am showing for the project structure is dummy, just to give a concept of how I am doing it.